# copy file in Windows Makefile

Tags: windows, bash, makefile

I am not familiar how to run bash commands in Windows Makefile.

for instance I want to copy a file target.txt in out/a to another directory out/b(my current working directory is out).

I tried

```
 cp /y a\target.txt b
```

in my cmd, and it works.

So I wonder if in my Windows makefile, how can I run that command? should I add a $ sign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the simple answer isn't actually worth an answer: *just do it*.

In case there are misunderstandings: Whatever you have in a *recipe line* of a makefile, or as arguments to `$(shell )`, is fed to the system's shell. On windows, the shell is `cmd` and cmd will understand your `copy` command.

---

But **there is a pitfall**: Shells like `bash` (I'll call them *posix shells* now) are available for windows as well. For example, `msys` (a minimal build environment for `mingw`) comes with `bash`. GNU make on windows will prefer a posix shell when it finds one and only use `cmd` as a fallback.

This however means your makefile should be prepared to run in both `cmd` and a posix shell for maximum compatibility with users' systems. It's a little tricky, but it can be done, e.g. with something like this:

```
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)

ifneq ($(strip $(filter %sh,$(basename $(realpath $(SHELL))))),)
POSIXSHELL := 1
else
POSIXSHELL :=
endif

else
# not on windows:
POSIXSHELL := 1

endif

ifneq ($(POSIXSHELL),)

CMDSEP := ;
PSEP := /
CPF := cp -f
# more variables for commands you need

else

CMDSEP := &
PSEP := \\
CPF := copy /y
# more variables for commands you need

endif
```

Then you could use a line like this in a recipe:

```
$(CPF) a$(PSEP)target.txt b
```